# Reactivity issue when using vue-chartjs v4 with `chartjs-plugin-trendline`

Tags: vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I have a linear line chart and a button to toggle the visibility of the trendline.
Showing the trendline works fine, but when I click the button again to hide the trendline, nothing happens.
I have no idea why, perhaps it's a bug in `vue-chartjs` v4.2.1 or maybe I'm doing something wrong with my code. I even try to manually update the chart via ref, but no luck.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <line-chart
      ref="chart"
      :chartData="chartData"
      :chartOptions="chartOptions"
    />
    <button @click="toggleTrendline">
      {{ showTrendline ? "Hide" : "Show" }} trendline
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs/legacy";

export default {
  components: { "line-chart": Line },
  data() {
    return {
      showTrendline: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      return {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      };
    },
    chartData() {
      let data = {
        labels: [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
          "August",
          "September",
          "October",
          "November",
          "December",
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: "#f87979",
            data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11],
          },
        ],
      };
      if (this.showTrendline)
        data.datasets[0].trendlineLinear = {
          colorMin: "#2d9cdb",
          colorMax: "#2d9cdb",
          lineStyle: "solid",
          width: 2,
        };
      else delete data.datasets[0].trendlineLinear;
      return data;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTrendline() {
      this.showTrendline = !this.showTrendline;
      if (!this.showTrendline) {
        this.$refs.chart.getCurrentChart().update("none");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is a reproducible sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-demo-forked-kujr7m?file=/src/components/LineChart.vue:0-1463

Here is a working version with vanilla js: https://codesandbox.io/s/working-trendline-q31h0o?file=/src/index.js
It works fine with vanilla js, so I believe either my vue code is wrong or vue-chartjs has a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
else
data.datasets[0].trendlineLinear = null;
```

[See this code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-demo-forked-5m8edd?file=/src/components/LineChart.vue)

Comment: Hmm, this actually works and must more simple than other suggestions. I'll accept this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Didnt test this on runtime, but maybe the logic should work like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <line-chart ref="chart" :chartData="data" :chartOptions="chartOptions" />
    <button @click="toggleTrendline">
      {{ showTrendline ? "Hide" : "Show" }} trendline
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs/legacy";

export default {
  components: { "line-chart": Line },
  data() {
    const dataset = {
      label: "Data One",
      backgroundColor: "#f87979",
      data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11],
    };

    return {
      showTrendline: false,
      dataset: dataset,
      data: {
        labels: [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
          "August",
          "September",
          "October",
          "November",
          "December",
        ],
        datasets: [dataset],
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      return {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTrendline() {
      this.showTrendline = !this.showTrendline;
      if (this.showTrendline) {
        this.$refs.chart.$data._chart.data.datasets[0].trendlineLinear = {
          colorMin: "#2d9cdb",
          colorMax: "#2d9cdb",
          lineStyle: "solid",
          width: 2,
        };
      } else {
        delete this.$refs.chart.$data._chart.data.datasets[0].trendlineLinear;
      }

      console.log(this.$refs.chart.$data._chart);

      this.$refs.chart.$data._chart.update();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: update: 

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-demo-forked-wh4gx1?file=/src/components/LineChart.vue

yea it works

Comment: Yes, it does work, but it looks like we're updating the data directly in chart.js and as I mentioned it works fine when I use just chartjs without vue-chartjs. I'd like to keep the reactivity from `vue-chartjs`

Comment: i think you cant do that since vue-chartjs is just a chartjs wrapper for vue. and if you read the code here "https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/blob/main/src/chart.ts" the only thing you can get is "chart" instance since its the only one being exposed to get from refs. And it works the same like what i show on the code example

Comment: but the code internally has watcher for the data props that use the same chart update. hmmm

Comment: I'm using vue-chart js v4.2.1. So the code in the `main` branch is not the one you should read. I think it's in the `v4` branch. They do have a watcher for `chartData`, so theoretically, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the vue reactivity works just fine, it's probably a bug on the `"chartjs-plugin-trendline"` plugin. We can prove that the reactivity actually works, because when we change the value of the `trendlineLinear` property, the chart changes just fine. The way I see it, it's probably that the chart (maybe on this version) simply can't remove the `trendlineLinear` once it's created, but i'm not really sure about that. The only easy workaround I could think of is, instead of deleting the `trendLineLinear` property, we change the color of the trendline to `transparent` when we want to hide it.

```
      ...
      if (this.showTrendline)
        data.datasets[0].trendlineLinear = {
          colorMin: "#2d9cdb",
          colorMax: "#2d9cdb",
          lineStyle: "solid",
          width: 2,
        };
      else
        data.datasets[0].trendlineLinear = {
          colorMin: "rgba(0,0,0, 0)",
          colorMax: "rgba(0,0,0, 0)",
          lineStyle: "solid",
          width: 2,
        };
      ...
```

[Here is the working forked code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-demo-forked-lxle4n?file=/src/components/LineChart.vue).

Comment: Oh yes, that's indeed a good workaround. Thanks for pointing it out.